# How do you use two different jQuery versions with one being injected by a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Situation: I wrote a Chrome Extension that adds very different kinds of functionalities to a website. I'm using JQuery almost everywhere in my code, since I'm doing work that would require way more code in native JS. My jQuery Version is listed only under Content Scripts in my manifest.

Problem: The website my Extension is written for already injects a very old JQuery Version themselves and a lot of their scripts depend on it. They inject it using a normal script tag in the `<head>`. Now I want to use my own jQuery Version (the newer one) for all my own scripts in my extension, and the site scripts should remain using their old version. Basically I want my jQuery Version to be completely separated from theirs but I fail to get that to work. Whenever I call jQuery from any of my content scripts it uses the old version that is injected into the site, instead of the new version in my content scripts.

I tried using jQuery's noConflict (and maybe use a different shortcut than $) but when I use my Extension to append a script to the Document with $.noConflict(true), the noConflict is used by the site's version of jQuery and all their scripts break because $ is no longer available to them.

I know having two versions of jQuery loaded on the same page is never ideal, but I need the newer jQuery for my code and I can't force the site scripts to use the newer version because of their code.

Is there a way to tell jQuery to use noConflict WHILE you inject it?

Or maybe there is a a way to separate the newer jQuery completely and tell the Extension to not use the one injected into the site?

Comment: You could append the `noConflict` statement to the jQuery script itself.

Comment: @Bergi Where would I do that? I tried but always got Errors.

Comment: Just edit the script file that contains the jQuery code.

Comment: You are talking about the jQuery Source Code right? Like here: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js

Where would I add the noConflict now?

Comment: You don't need to append your script to DOM because the content scripts are already running just fine, fully isolated from the page so you can use jQuery as is, without noConflict.

Comment: Okay and what about elements my extension needs to insert into the DOM of the page? They will use the pages JQuery instead of mine